# Distinct on specific columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct

I know someone on here already asked the similar questions. However, most of them still want to return the first row or last row if multiple rows have the same attributes. For my case, I want to simply discard the rows which have the same specific attributes.

For example, I have a toy dataset like this:

```
gender age  name
  f     20   zoe
  f     20   natalia
  m     39   tom
  f     20   erika 
  m     37   eric
  m     37   shane
  f     22   jenn
```

I only want to distinct on `gender` and `age`, then discard all rows if those two attributes, which returns:

```
gender age  name
  m     39   tom
  f     22   jenn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the window (analytic) variant of `count` to find the rows that have a just one occurance of the gender/age combination:

```
SELECT gender, age, name
FROM   (SELECT gender, age, name, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY gender, age) AS cnt
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `HAVING` clause in a CTE.

```
;WITH DistinctGenderAges AS
(
    SELECT gender
        ,age
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY gender
        ,age
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
SELECT yt.gender, yt.age, yt.name
FROM DistinctGenderAges dga
INNER JOIN YourTable yt ON dga.gender = yt.gender AND dga.age = yt.age
```

Comment: Name is not part of the distinct

Comment: @Paparazzi my answer has been updated and now works as OP intended.

Answer (score -1):

No matter what, you have to tell the database which value to pick for name. If you don't care an easy solution is to group:

```
SELECT gender, age, MIN(name) as name FROM mytable GROUP BY gender, age HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

You can use any valid aggregate for name, but you have to pick something.

Comment: This doesn't filter out the records with multiples.

Comment: Right, the wording didn't make sense to me. I will amend.

Comment: I don't have a testing platform at the moment but when all rows with multiple corresponding records are eliminated by the `HAVING COUNT(*)=1`, this is exactly what the result will be.